# How to work with nested zip archives in java?

Tags: java, zip

i have a question about how to organize writing in nested `zip` archive in java?

For example `b.zip` is enclosed in `a.zip`. How can I write to `b.zip` ?

Comment: Did you try to code something for this? Did you run into problems with code you've written?

Comment: @ItamarGreen The aim is to create nested archives in the archive file, then create nested archives in them and so on.(at the output we have a tree whose leaves are the archives, 
and we must create this tree starting from the top)  And it is not clear how to organize the entry into nested archives?
How to link with nested archives streams to write data to them?